# How to change the word "blog" for "journal"

Tags: string-overrides

I have used string overwrites for a lot of stuff but sometimes I hit a section I cannot change. One of these is the "User's blog" button. How do I change the word "blog" for "journal"? I am impressed no one seems to have asked this question before.

Comment: There are so many questions in site about your context, but its true that no one want to change the word "blog" for "journal"..

Comment: I agree with nikhil. This question has been asked tons of times here on dse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in settings.php

```
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  "!username's blog"      => "!username's journal",
);
```

You'll need to include the variable placeholder in the source / translation string.

More info: [blog_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!blog!blog.module/function/blog_node_view/7)

Answer (score 0):

There is [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.

Features

- Easily replace anything that's passed through t()
- Locale support, allowing you to override strings in any language
- Ability to import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
- Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need a few easy text changes.

Comment: I actually had that installed but using the settings file works better (one less module to use). I only use these for a few text changes (I think so far I have 10 - 15).

Answer (score 0):

[hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7):

> Alter the data being saved to the {menu_router} table after hook_menu is invoked.

With [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module, do a `dpm` on `$items` and change the title var to what you want it to be.